# How to update multiple nodes in a transaction (Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

For the following database sample structure:

```
  {
    "stats": {
      "posts_count": 231,
      "posts_by_category": {
        "sports": {
          "count": 12,
          "foo": "bar"
        }
      },
      "posts_by_language": {
        "english": {
          "count": 12,
          "foo": "bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And given a new post in [english, sports] categories, how can I run a transaction with the following changes:

```
stats/posts_count +1
stats/posts_by_category/sports/count +1
stats/posts_by_language/english/count +1
```

Basically I don't know how to navigate/edit the MutableData object to reflect the changes, and I'd like an example (preferably without using DAO classes)

```
db.getReference("stats").runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
    override fun doTransaction(currentData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
        ????
        return Transaction.success(currentData)
    }

    override fun onComplete(
        error: DatabaseError?,
        committed: Boolean,
        currentData: DataSnapshot?
    ) {
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions run on a single node. So if you want to update multiple branches in the database transactionally, you'll have to run a single transaction on the lowest common ancestor node. In your example that'd be `stats`. Note that this may create a lot of contention on the write operation. If the `stats` node may be updated by many clients around the same time, this may result in many retries and possibly event failed transactions.

In your example though, you seem to want to increment counters, which Firebase Realtime Database supports as a native operation since earlier this year. So instead of running a transaction on `stats`, I'd run the following update operation on it:

```
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
updates.put("posts_count", ServerValue.increment(1));
updates.put("posts_by_category/sports/count", ServerValue.increment(1));
updates.put("posts_by_language/english/count", ServerValue.increment(1));
db.getReference("stats").updateChildren(updates);
```

Things to note here:

- The `/` in the keys here is a special notation that allows updating nested properties.
- The `ServerValue.increment(1)` is sent to the database as a marker, and is then executed atomically by the database.